# What are Cookies SQL injection?

Tags: cookies, vulnerability

After applying web vulnerability scan on a site that I have, I found a vulnerability called Cookie SQL injection, and applied on the requested cookie.
What is this vulnerability? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you look this up at all? There is a lot of material on this: https://www.google.com/search?q=cookie+sql+injection The scanner should have have an explanation of the vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure it is just what the name implies -

A cookie is a key/value pair which is sent between the server and client to track state between web pages.     SQL injection is tricking the application to forward an SQL statement to the database server and have it run the statement (this can result in dumping or changing information in the database - often including login credentials which can give you full access to the site).

What I expect Cookie SQL injection is is a user modifying/setting a cookie and sending this to the server.  The server then processes the information in this cookie but it is possible to trick the server to send information in the cookie to the SQL server in such a way that it can be executed.

Its impossible to advise how to solve it in the specific case without more information - but in general when the server receives the cookie it should be sanitized before use in such a way that it can't cause SQL to run.  Very often languages provide a means of escaping input to prevent SQL injections - but how you do this might also depend on what you are doing with the cookie.

As a best practice, never trust user input.   Always sanitize it (even cookies).   Similarly, using prepared statements can prevent/frustrate SQL injections as in theory they can't be tricked into running arbitrary SQL as the statement is built and set up with the database server before input and then the data provided is treated as parameters.

Comment: More generally, never trust *anything* (not just user input) that is returned by a user's machine.  Even if it should only be returning something (such as a cookie) that you previously set on that machine, or the output of Javascript that you put on your web site.

Comment: Yeah. Bad wording on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The best solutions to SQL Injection (regardless of vector) are generally multi-layered, and involve at a minimum:

1. validate and sanitize ALL input, be it from URL args, Cookie values, user input, etc.
2. Use a clear architecture for your application, that never puts SQL code in the UI tier. SQL should be handled in a data access layer of some kind, seperate from the User Interface. Above all else, NEVER concatenate SQL command strings and execute them.
3. Utilize an ORM or similar abstraction for DB access, or at the very least use parameterized queries, stored procedures, etc for queries and DML statements. This prevents the injected text from being executed as part of the query.
4. utilize a web application firewall (WAF), to filter out requests that contain malicious input.

As for your specific finding, search for a place in the code where you have concatenated a sql statement that contains input from the cookie in question.

Hope that helps!